# How to get next character everytime I run the loop

Tags: python

So I have the following code for a Hangman game. I need it to go through all the characters in the random word, but I can't get it go to get the next character in the word.

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

random_choice = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Please Guess a letter ")

choice_length = len(random_choice)

display_spaces = []
for letter_spaces in range(choice_length):
  display_spaces.append('_',)

print(display_spaces)
for letter in random_choice:
  if guess == letter:
    letter_place = random_choice.index(letter)
    display_spaces[letter_place] = letter
    random_choice.replace(letter, "1")
print(display_spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `while` to keep playing until there are no more spaces in the word.

```py
while ' ' in display_places:
  guess = input("Please Guess a letter ")
  for i, letter in enumerate(random_choice):
    if guess == letter: 
      display_places[i] = guess
  print(display_spaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an additional loop that encapsulates asking for the user input, this will simulate turns.  Without the extra loop your player only gets one turn and then the game ends.

```py
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]

random_choice = random.choice(word_list)
choice_length = len(random_choice)

display_spaces = []
for letter_spaces in range(choice_length):
  display_spaces.append('_',)
print(display_spaces)

for _ in range(choice_length):                # this line is the added loop
    guess = input("Please Guess a letter ")   # for each iteration the 
    for letter in random_choice:              # player guesses a new letter
        if guess == letter:                   # ...
            letter_place = random_choice.index(letter)
            display_spaces[letter_place] = letter
            random_choice.replace(letter, "1")
    print(display_spaces)
```

You can adjust the number of "turns" the user gets by changing the argument to the top loop's `range` function.